# Java Servlet Proxy

Tags: java, servlets, proxy

If I set the system to use a proxy in the doPost method of a servlet will all out going connections in the method go through the proxy? Example:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myProxyServer.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80"); 


CONNECTING TO A THIRD PARTY HERE.

}
```

Comment: Basically, yes. Are you having problems?

Comment: @kolossus It was just a theoretical question, however if im using an api that makes a connection it will still go through the proxy right, because the proxy is at the system level?